# Hangfire Asp MVC 5 - User Specific Jobs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I have a web app where users have to login (authentication is done via identity framework) and then they can create a hangfire job (any type of hangfire job i.e fire and forget, delayed, recurring).

Now everything works, except that the hangfire dashboard is showing all jobs created by anyone. So i believe that I have to some how tie a job with a user manually ?!

My question is, whats the best way to associate hangfire jobs with a user account ? is there any built in functionality for that , that i dont know of?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in for that, and out of the box I don't think the interface has extensibility points for you to do that. You'd either need to fork Hangfire or create your own custom UI.

Comment: It shouldn't be all that hard to make your own UI, the database layout is fairly simple.

Comment: thanks guys. i will start looking into hangfire source code and the database as well